# Link in video not clickable on mobile (iOS) in power saving mode

Tags: html, video, mobile, html5-video, battery-saver

I have an autoplay video on my site which also serves as a link to another page. But now I found a problem in the power saving mode of the iPhone. Clicking on the video plays the video. But when I click again nothing happens. However, I would like the integrated link to open.

My code:

```css
video {
  width: 80vw;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <a href="http://www.google.com">
    <video autoplay loop playsinline src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" target="_self"></video>
  </a>
</body>
```

Can you help me so that the link also opens in power saving mode?

Comment: I ran your code and a few things happened. First, no video. Second, Upon clicking an area that could've been the link, I got a "blocked by content security policy". Can you explain what happened there?

Comment: should work now.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with JS and an `onclick` event.

```js
const targetURL = "404.404";
// Not a real address

function openURL() {
  window.location = targetURL;
}
```

```css
video {
  width: 80vw;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <video onclick="openURL()" autoplay loop playsinline src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" target="_self"></video>


</body>
```

404.404 is not a real URL, it is just to produce a 404 error and demonstrate that the code redirects.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! But the video is still not clickable in power saving mode on iOS.

Comment: @Mauro And it works without power saving on everything else?